# OpenGL - Light values and position

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut, lighting

This is how i have declared my light values and their positions

is this correct or is there another more officiant way?

```
// Lighting values
GLfloat  greenLight[] = { 0.0f, 0.6f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat  redLight[] = { 0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat  blueLight[] = { 0.0f, 0.6f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat  whiteLight[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
GLfloat  sourceLight[] = { 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f };


GLfloat  lightPos[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat  lightPos1[] = { 5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
GLfloat  lightPos2[] = { -5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
GLfloat  lightPos3[] = { 5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't any other way to do it using fixed-function OpenGL. Setting the parameters is a small part of the cost of lighting. If you want something more efficient, I would recommend you learn non-deprecated OpenGL and implement lighting in a shader, which will probably be faster than fixed-function lighting.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rob i think I will look into that actually always wondered how to implement lighting in a shader :) always good to know extra info

Comment: Here's a good guide to starting with GLSL and it includes a phong lighting shader: http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~emmanuel/courses/cs543/slides/cliff_iintro_glsl_final.pdf